# List in recyle bin wont restore - possibly too large a list?

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, error, restore

I am using Sharepoint Foundation 2010 and its been great for a number of years.

However i have a list that is in the recycle bin 10424.4 MB in size so its a pretty large list.

Im trying to recover it but when i tick it and click restore selection it seems to act like its restoring but say 20-30 seconds later the page just seems to crash and i just get a blank white page. Then when i go back to the recycle bin the List is still there and hasnt been restored. Ive tried this many time, restarting everything and so on but nothing has changed.

I have other lists and created a single item in those lists, deleted, restored and those havent been a problem (so i assume its something due to the actual size of the list maybe? maybe its timing out when its attempting to restore?)

Any ideas as to what i could do to restore it as im totally lost right now. Youd be saving my life literally, thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I got this from the Log. Not so sure what it means though

---

07/10/2019 15:39:14.27  w3wp.exe (0x0F20)                           0x0C88  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The item "Orders Portal" cannot be restored.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinUtility.ThrowAppropriateRestoreException(SPRecycleBinRestoreErrorData errorData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRecycleBinItemCollection.RestoreCore(Guid[] ids)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.RecycleBinPage.ProcessAction(String action, String guidString)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.RecycleBinPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    265b0c30-dfb6-40b5-821f-bca82086dfe3